# Bash script for killing processes with a certain name

Tags: linux, bash

I've written the following script to kill processes named "client" and "server". When I run it I get:

> : No such file or directory

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash 

function killThem {
        while read -a line; do
                kill -9 ${line[0]}
        done
}

ps | grep -w client | cut -d" " -f1 | killThem
ps | grep -w server | cut -d" " -f1 | killThem
```

Does anyone have any idea why I get this error?

Comment: Have you looked at [`killall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) or [`pkill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill)?

Comment: Killall is what you want. By the way, you should *not* use kill -9 normally, since that doesn't give the processes any chance to clean up. Always try `kill pid` or `kill -15 pid` first, and send a kill -9 if the process doesn't exit after a few seconds.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm `pkill` tend to be safer... `killall` does horrible things on some other Unix-like systems...

Comment: `pgrep` tend to be a better way to find PIDs than `grep`. As in `kill -9 $(pgrep '\<client\>')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are reinventing killall but anyway:

```
 kill -9 ${line[0]}
```

should be

```
 kill -9 ${line}
```